# Why does my use of layer.xaxis.tickfont.size not do anything in Plotly.JS?

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

Here is a snippet of my code in which I set a number of parameters for Plotly's Layout object to change font size, family, and color.  But, when run, the size never changes - yet all the other changes work:

```
const layout: Partial<Layout> = {
        dragmode: "pan", // make plot draggable by default
        showlegend: false,
        autosize: true,
        useResizeHandler: true,
        height: undefined,
        width: undefined,
        title: "Estimated wealth over time",
        yaxis: { tickfont: {size: 24, color: 'red', family: 'Arial, sans-serif' },
                 title: "Wealth ($M)", showgrid: true,
               },
        xaxis: {tickfont: {size: 36, color: 'blue'},
                 title: "Age", showgrid: false, autorange: true, type: "category",
                 dtick: 5,
           },   };
```

Just to be clear I am doing what the documentation says.  Here is a CodePen I ran across which sets the font size for the X axis that works.

```
 var layout = {
  autosize: false,
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  xaxis: {tickfont: {size: 36, color: "blue"}},
  margin: {
    l: 50,
    r: 50,
    b: 100,
    t: 100,
    pad: 4,
  },
  paper_bgcolor: '#7f7f7f',
  plot_bgcolor: '#c7c7c7'
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

Which gives this (correctly):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Set autosize to false:

```
const layout: Partial<Layout> = {
  dragmode: "pan",
  showlegend: false,
  autosize: false, // Set autosize to false
  useResizeHandler: true,
  height: undefined,
  width: undefined,
  title: "Estimated wealth over time",
  yaxis: {
    tickfont: { size: 24, color: 'red', family: 'Arial, sans-serif' },
    title: "Wealth ($M)",
    showgrid: true,
  },
  xaxis: {
    tickfont: { size: 36, color: 'blue' },
    title: "Age",
    showgrid: false,
    autorange: true,
    type: "category",
    dtick: 5,
  },
};
```

Option 2: Set tick font size after defining the layout:

```
const layout: Partial<Layout> = {
  dragmode: "pan",
  showlegend: false,
  autosize: true,
  useResizeHandler: true,
  height: undefined,
  width: undefined,
  title: "Estimated wealth over time",
  yaxis: {
    tickfont: { size: 24, color: 'red', family: 'Arial, sans-serif' },
    title: "Wealth ($M)",
    showgrid: true,
  },
  xaxis: {
    title: "Age",
    showgrid: false,
    autorange: true,
    type: "category",
    dtick: 5,
  },
};

// Set tick font size separately
layout.xaxis.tickfont.size = 36;
layout.xaxis.tickfont.color = 'blue';
```

Comment: I tried (1) turning off autosize; (2) explicitly setting the attributes, as suggested; and (3) both at the same time.  While this looked like (and I hoped was) the solution, but it made no difference.